# What's an equivalent way of saying *friolenta* (from Spanish)?

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives, north-american-english

My aunt is *friolenta*.  She gets cold easily.

But is there a better way to say this, that stays closer to the original construction, by being a simple adjective?

Idle curiosity would make me interested to know if there's a universally understood britishism but for me to use on a regular basis I would prefer something understandable in the U.S.

(In French it's *frileuse*.  Per Mari-LouA in Italian it's *freddolosa*.)

Comment: Staying close to the original construction would lead to you saying your aunt is frigid, which is almost certainly not what you mean!

Comment: ELU is not a translation site.

Comment: @Gary But we are interested in foreign words which appear not to have any direct equivalent in English. Apart from anything else it potentially introduces a new italicised *mot juste* to our language.

Comment: The question is essentially "Is there a one-word paraphrase of 'gets cold easily' used of a human?" This is clearly not specifically a translation request. However, 'gets cold easily' is not well-defined. It's probably a paraphrase of the somewhat more precise 'is particularly sensitive to the cold'.

Comment: This question has been asked, but if I vote to close it as a duplicate it will be immediately closed, I have a dupe hammer, so... here's just the link. See if you can make your question appear unique https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/308177/english-expression-for-cold-natured-without-emotional-connotation I don't think asking for an English translation is sufficient. Personally, I like the expression *nesh* but I have no idea how well-known it is within the British Isles or for that matter, in the US.

Comment: Here's another question with the same top answer https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/101281/adjective-for-a-person-who-really-suffers-when-it-is-cold

Comment: Possible duplicate of [English expression for "cold-natured" without emotional connotation?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/308177/english-expression-for-cold-natured-without-emotional-connotation)

Comment: @Mari-Lou You're actually prevented from doing right by your laudable principles! Can't you apply to have your dupe-hammer made optional? //  'Nesh' is in my experience strongly pejorative (see [ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/nesh)). Think 'wimpish'. Though [Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/nesh) gives the non-wimpish sense first. I'm not happy about that. [M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/nesh) is just about in the ODO camp, I'd say.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I have voted to close questions as duplicates in the past forgetting that I have this "curse" and finding the question immediately closed :) but luckily I don't close unless I am convinced. In aparente001's case, I think he should be given the opportunity to tweak his question. Or explicitly exclude "nesh" and explain why.

Comment: @Mari-Lou ... [BBC South Yorkshire](http://www.bbc.co.uk/southyorkshire/content/articles/2005/08/16/voices_sywords_feature.shtml) has an article seemingly championing the non-pejorative sense, but includes the telling << ... Judith Cockroft: 
'My mum who has recently passed away lived in Halifax West Yorkshire but was born and brought up in Rawmarsh South Yorkshire. Mum always used to tell us we were "nesh" if we complained about being cold.' >>.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth fair enough, but the OP is American, so he probably wants a term that his fellow Americans will easily understand, (I suspect "nesh" without context would be meaningless) or maybe, in the end, he'll be happy with a quirky N.England expression. I see the votes to close are picking up the momentum!

Comment: I can't accept my own answer until tomorrow.  If the question is still open then, I'll accept "poor circulation" and then close the question.  If someone else posts "poor circulation" before then, and I notice it, I'll accept it, delete my answer, and close the question.

Comment: I’ve always called such people _popsicles_, but I think that’s probably quite localised—perhaps even idiolectic. “My aunt is such a popsicle” has a nice ring to it, though.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet - Could be understood anywhere with some context, I think.  Cute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***runs cold***

> run ([www.dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/run))
>
> 51. to be or continue to be of a certain or average size, number, etc.:
>     *Potatoes are running large this year.*

So, for the example sentence:

> My aunt runs cold.  My son runs hot.

See, for example, https://www.mamapedia.com/article/does-your-child-run-hot-or-cold.

It's similar to

> This shoe runs small.  You might want to try a half size larger.

Comment: Interesting. I’ve never come across this usage before. Potatoes running large and even (at a bit of a stretch to me) shoes running small, those are normal enough. But “My aunt runs cold” would have been meaningless to me out of context five minutes ago.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet - I heard it from a shoe salesman.  He runs hot.  I run cold.  I'm happy -- I found a good way to say someone is *friolento* in English.

Answer (score 1):

This definition of *cold-blooded* fits:

> - noticeably sensitive to cold
>     <sub>[Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/cold-blooded)</sub>

However, you need to be sure to provide enough context to ensure people don't assume another definition:

> - done or acting without consideration, compunction, or clemency cold-blooded murder
>     <sub>ibid</sub>

Comment: In parts of England we have a dialect word, **nesh**, which means just that. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nesh

Comment: @KateBunting--I guarantee you that if you used nesh in the US, no one would understand you.

Comment: @Kate I’ve come across _nesh_ a few times, but about half those times, it didn’t have anything to do with temperature—it had the meaning Edwin mentioned in the comments to the question: wimpy, feeble, cowardly, sissy. It would seem that this is a word most safely kept to a local sphere where you know beforehand that your listeners will understand the word the same way you do. Otherwise you may end up being rather more insulting to your aunt than you meant to be.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't realize this has already been asked at least twice.  Of all the answers contributed here and in the other threads, I like [this one](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/308431/112436) best, thanks to @AndyT:

> My aunt *has poor circulation*.

It isn't one word, but I like it the best of all the options I saw.

Edwin's "is particularly sensitive to the cold" runs a close second.